# How To Get Total Value Of Inputs With Vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the total amount from input value with pure JavaScript but It's returning blank. The *format* of the amount value for each input is as follow `0.00`

PHP

```
//rest of code
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {$i++;
    <input id="Amount'.$i.'"  name="Amount" value="'.$plan['price'].'" type="text">
}

echo ' <input id="total"  name="finalResult" value="" type="text">';
```

JS

```
function totalResult(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('Amount');
    var total=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            total += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value = total;
}
```

Comment: Whats returning blank ? Can you paste an example of the generated HTML displayed in the browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTML5's query selctor API `querySelectorAll()` like the following:

```js
function totalResult(){
    var arr = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=Amount]');
    var total=0;
    arr.forEach(function(item){
      if(parseInt(item.value))
            total += parseInt(item.value);
    });
    document.getElementById('total').value = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);
}
totalResult();
```

```html
<input id="Amount1"  name="Amount" value="10.00" type="text" />
<input id="Amount2"  name="Amount" value="20.00" type="text" />
<input id="Amount3"  name="Amount" value="30.00" type="text" /><br>
Result: 
<input id="total"  name="finalResult" value="" type="text">
```

Comment: Also, you need `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt` since the input value format is mentioned as `0.00`.